# os: process already finished when sending syscall.SIGCONT (possible bug?)

Tags: go, signals, system-calls

When executing a process and sending signals to it using: [Process.Signal](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Signal) I notice that after sending the second signal `syscall.SIGCONT` I got a: `os: process already finished` but if using [syscall.Kill](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Kill) everything works as expected.

For demonstrative purposes I have created this naive example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    exit := make(chan error, 1)
    go run(exit)

    for {
        select {
        case <-exit:
            println("fin, restarting")
            run(exit)
        default:
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            println("running...")
        }
    }
}

func run(ch chan<- error) {
    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "3")
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        print(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Pid: %d\n", cmd.Process.Pid)
    go func() {
        ch <- cmd.Wait()
    }()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGSTOP))

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    // Using this will return an os: process already finished  
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGCONT)) 

    // This works as expected
    //fmt.Printf("%v\n", syscall.Kill(cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGCONT))
}
```

So basically if using:

```
cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGCONT)
```

`os: process already finished` is returned

But when using:

```
syscall.Kill(cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGCONT)
```

It works as expected.

Could this be a bug on [os.exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) or it the expected behavior?

**UPDATE**: seems to be happening only on mac os X

Comment: You have a race condition on the command structure. You need to fix that first before you can define the behavior of this program.

Comment: @JimB, Hi, could you please help me understand where is the race condition or how to test it? thanks in advance.

Comment: The race is easy, run the race detector and it will tell you exactly where it is. I figured out what you're looking at though, it seems darwin returns from a first wait4 on SIGSTOP even though WEXITED is set, marking the process as done and preventing further signals. It will only happen if there is a concurrent Wait being called. I'm not sure if Go can fix this is the darwin kernel isn't cooperating.

Comment: @JimB many thanks, if I am right as a cross-platform solution by using `syscall.Kill(cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGCONT)` should work right?

Comment: Yes, that should work for most cases. It has the problem that always exists where the PID may not exist or belong to the correct process when you send the signal, but that's a general unix issue. Just make sure you synchronize the calls properly, and check with the race detector ;)

Comment: @JimB, Hi, I fixed the race condition, probably not in the best way but at leat hope it can help to demonstrate this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19314) seems to be only happening on Mac OS X, tested on "Sierra" and "El Capitan"  https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/37610/

So, for now, to keep things cross-platform better user:

```
syscall.Kill(cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGCONT))
```

Example code to test if your system has this issue:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "10")
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // signal when wait4 will return immediately
    go func() {
        var siginfo [128]byte
        psig := &siginfo[0]
        _, _, e := syscall.Syscall6(syscall.SYS_WAITID, 1, uintptr(cmd.Process.Pid), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(psig)), syscall.WEXITED|syscall.WNOWAIT, 0, 0)
        fmt.Println("WAITID RETURNED -- this shouldn't happen:", e)
    }()

    err := cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGSTOP)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    cmd.Wait()
}
```